# Problem with flipping images in Pygame (python)

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to create a game in which you can move a character with arrow keys. When moving left or right, I want the character (an image) to flip and point left/right accordingly. The original image/character is pointing left.  But I cannot get the character to flip, please help me, thanks.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()#initiate pygame
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
display_width = 1200
display_height = 800
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
characterimg = pygame.image.load(r'/Users/ye57324/Desktop/Make/coding/python/characterimg.png')
def soldier(x,y):
    display.blit(characterimg, (x,y))
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.1)
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#game clock
flip_right = False
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
start = True


while start:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            start = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change += -5
                if flip_right == True:
                    pygame.transform.flip(characterimg, True, False)
                    flip_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += 5
                if flip_right == False:
                    pygame.transform.flip(characterimg, True, False)
                    flip_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change += -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change += 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change += -5

    x += x_change
    y += y_change
    display.fill(white)
    soldier(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)#fps
```

Comment: You're never changing the value of `flip_right`. I'm assuming you meant to adjust its value after you flip the image to reflect eh direction your character is currently looking.

Comment: Oh yeah right, but after I added it, it still doesnt work

Comment: I just looked up the documentation of `flip`, as you could've done. It says "Flipping a Surface is non-destructive and returns a new Surface with the same dimensions.". This means the surface you path isn't altered, i.e., you should write `characterimg = pygame.transform.flip(characterimg...)`. Learn to read the docs! :)

Comment: Read it up yourself: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip

Comment: This means that the method `flip` doesn't alter any data contained in the surface you pass, i.e. `characterimg`. It only reads the data and then writes the flipped image onto a _new_ surface, which it then returns. (PS: I meant to  say "the surface you **pass** isn't altered"). This is why you have to overwrite your `characterimg` variable. So that it contains the new, flipped version of your surface.

Comment: No, I'm **re**-assigning `characterimg`. Your `characterimg` is the surface that you blit in your `soldier` method, right? So whatever surface `characterimg` currently points to gets blitted on screen. So we need to make `characterimg` to point to the new, flipped version returned to by pygame.transform.flip(...).

Comment: @Nearoo Thank you so much! I solved it!

Comment: @Nearoo you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I'd also remove the `flip_right` variable and create the left and right images beforehand. Then you can just assign the current image to the `characterimg` variable when the user presses left or right, e.g. `characterimg = characterimg_left` and `characterimg = characterimg_right`.

Comment: @skrx good point. I've added this to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame's doc-page about `pygame.transform.flip` states

> Flipping a Surface is non-destructive and returns a new Surface with the same dimensions.

This means that the surface you pass to that method remains unaffected. You have to keep the *return*-value around in order to see any effect.

In practice, this means that you should replace

```
pygame.transform.flip(characterimg, True, False)
```

with

```
characterimg = pygame.transform.flip(characterimg, True, False)
```

So that `characterimg` point to the new, flipped version of the image.

**Note:** Performance wise, this is not a very good method of doing things. Each time you call `pygame.transform.flip`, pygame has to allocated new memory for the new surface, go over each pixel of the original surface and copy it over to the new surface, transforming its position in the process. You'd better flip the image once at the beginning of your program, so that you have a variable `characterimg_left` and `characterimg_right` and then just assign those to your `characterimg` variable.